# To prove a sequence converges, sufficient to show that difference between consecutive terms goes to 0?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of reals, where there exists $0 < r < 1$ and $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq \mathbb{N}_0$, $|a_n - a_{n-1}|\leq r|a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}|$. I want to show that the sequence converges. I know that $|a_n - a_{n-1}| \leq r^{n-1}|a_1 - a_0| \rightarrow 0$. Is this enough to conclude that the sequence converges (in $\mathbb{R}$)? If not, what else do I need?

Comment: It's not sufficient that the difference between consecutive terms tends to $0$. Consider $c_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$. The difference in your case however tends to $0$ very fast, while in my example, it tends to $0$ slowly. You must show that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. For that, it is sufficient to show that $\sum \lvert a_n - a_{n-1}\rvert < +\infty$.

Comment: For $n>m$, you have $$|a_n-a_m|\le\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} |a_k-a_{k-1}|$$ so you might be able to use this to show that $a_n$ is Cauchy

Comment: @DanielFischer Is that the sum from $1$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Since you start with $a_0$, yes. It would be $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty$ for those who don't count $0$ as a natural number.

Answer (score 1):

So we have $|a_n-a_m|\le\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} |a_k-a_{k-1}| \leq \sum_{k = m+1}^nr^{k-1}\ell = \ell (r^m - r^n)/(1-r)$ where $\ell = |a_1 - a_0|$ is some constant. To satisfy Cauchy condition, we need for every $\epsilon > 0$ an $N$ such that if $m \geq N$, then $\ell (r^m - r^n)< \epsilon(1-r)$. We can always find such $N$ because $\ell r^m \rightarrow 0$ (since $r < 1$).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the condition you describe is sufficient to prove convergence in $\mathbb{R}$.

To prove convergence, you need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, if you go far enough down the sequence so that all the remaining terms are within $\epsilon$ of each other.

In this case, try to construct an upper bound for $\vert a_m-a_n\vert $ where $n>m$, as a function of $m$.  Use the triangle inequality, and that geometric series with ratio terms in $(-1,1)$ always converge. Then show that this upper bound tends to zero as $m\to\infty$.